# Website doesn't load CSS or JS when I put a method in the URL

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have a file that get the controller and the method to be executed from the URL , when there is just the controller in the url it works fine but if I add the method to the url it wont load the css or any JS file correctly.

This is the folder of the project.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxTnD.png)

This is the .htaccess file

```
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     Options +FollowSymLinks
     RewriteEngine on
     # Send request via index.php
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?url=$1 [L]
     </IfModule>
```

This is the index file

```
    class url{
    public $controller = "home";
    public $method = "default";
    public $params = array();
    function __construct(){
    $url = $this->getUrl();
    if (file_exists("../app/controller/".$url[0].".php")){
   $this->controller = $url[0];
   unset($url[0]);
}
require_once("../app/controller/".$this->controller.".php");
$this->controller = new $this->controller();

if(isset($url[1])){
   if(method_exists($this->controller,$url[1])){
       $this->method = $url[1];
       unset($url[1]);
   }
$this->params = $url ? array_values($url): [];

}
call_user_func([$this->controller,$this->method],$this->params);
}



function  getUrl(){
if (isset($_GET["url"])){
$url = explode("/",$_GET["url"]);
return $url;
}
}
}
$url = new url();
```

This is the Controller

```
 class home{
function __construct(){

    echo "hola";
}
function default(){
    require_once("../app/views/home.php");
}
}
```

An this is the view

```
<head>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
<h1>Hey</h1>

</body>
```

Comment: Use absolute paths for css, images and js in you HTML.

Comment: i tried but it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> href="css/style.css"
> ```

You have a relative path.

The browser will take the URL, remove the query and fragment from it. Remove everything after the last `/`. Then append the path.

You need an **absolute** path, starting with a `/`.

```
href="/css/style.css"
```

The browser will strip off the entire path from the current URL. Not just the part after the last `/`.

Comment: So you felt, that this required posting an answer ?!

Comment: i tried but it didn't work!